# apache POI MS Office Excel can not open Font color set Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ms-office

I am facing a strange issue with apache poi

I am using apache poi 3.17 to create an Excel file.  If I set the font color then  the generated excel file is not opening with latest MS Office Excel viewer but it's opening with Libre Office and Mac OS Numbers app.

But If I comment out the 'urlFont.setColor((short)Color.BLACK.getRGB())' line then the generated file is opening with Ms Office Excel viewer(and  with rest of the apps also).

Did anyone face this issue?

```
 import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class WriteExcelBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String excelFileName = "/Users/home/Test3.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
        Font urlFont = wb.createFont();
        urlFont.setFontHeight((short)(9*20));
       // urlFont.setUnderline((byte)10);
        //urlFont.setBold(true);
       urlFont.setFontName("Arial");
        urlFont.setItalic(true);
      urlFont.setColor((short)Color.BLACK.getRGB());// commenting out this line will work



        style.setFont(urlFont);
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);


            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);


                Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
                String ss = "http://news.google.com/news/headlines?ned=us&hl=en";
                //String ss = "swasdqde";
               link.setAddress(ss);
                cell.setHyperlink(link);
                cell.setCellValue(ss);
                if(r == 1) {
                    System.out.println("In yellow");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.YELLOW));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("In red");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.RED));
                }
                cell.setCellStyle(style);


            }
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] myByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(myByteArray);
            fos.flush();
        }
        finally {
            wb.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed Font to XSFFFont and used XSSFCOLOR in that font and it's working.

Comment: Please, post this solution as an answer.

Comment: @FagnerFonseca Done

Answer (score 1):

I changed Font to XSFFFont and used XSSFCOLOR in that font and it's working.

```
import org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.HyperlinkType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class WriteExcelBasic {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String excelFileName = "/Users/home/Test3.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName);


        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
 XSSFFont urlFont = wb.createFont();// changed lines
 urlFont.setFontHeight((short)(9*20));
       // urlFont.setUnderline((byte)10);
        //urlFont.setBold(true);
       urlFont.setFontName("Arial");
        urlFont.setItalic(true);
      urlFont.setColor(new XSSFColor(Color.BLUE)); // changed lines



        style.setFont(urlFont);
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);


            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);


                Hyperlink link = wb.getCreationHelper().createHyperlink(HyperlinkType.URL);
                String ss = "http://news.google.com/news/headlines?ned=us&hl=en";
                //String ss = "swasdqde";
               link.setAddress(ss);
                cell.setHyperlink(link);
                cell.setCellValue(ss);
                if(r == 1) {
                    System.out.println("In yellow");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.YELLOW));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("In red");
                    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(new XSSFColor(Color.RED));
                }
                cell.setCellStyle(style);


            }
        }

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] myByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
            fos.write(myByteArray);
            fos.flush();
        }
        finally {
            wb.close();
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the correct approach for `XSSF` is given already, there is also the question why the [Font.setColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Font.html#setColor-short-) had not worked as expected.

The answer to this is that with `Font.setColor(short color)` the `short color` is **not** a `RGB` color value but is a index in an `IndexedColor` palette. This is an old approach from `HSSF` and the `BIFF` file format. There are 64 `IndexedColors` in the palette where 8 (32 to 39) are free for custom colors. `XSSF` is also able using this palette but is not able to store custom colors in it. And `Excel`, at least using `Excel 2007`, throws an error if the file is in Office Open XML format (`XSSF`) and the given index is greater than 220. `Excel 2016` is more tolerant there. Thats why the error while using `RGB` values there, which probably all are greater than 220 ;-).

The following example shows the usage of `Font.setColor(short color)` and its equivalent in [Enum IndexedColors](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html) and [HSSFPalette](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPalette.html) to store custom colors.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelFontColor {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  for (int c = 0; c < 221; c++) { //color index from 0 to 220
                                  //greater than 220 leads to an error while opening in Excel XSSF

   CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
   Font font = workbook.createFont();

   font.setColor((short)c);

   style.setFont(font);

   Row row = sheet.createRow(c);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Font color index " + c);

   cell.setCellStyle(style);

   IndexedColors indexedcolor = null;
   try {
    indexedcolor = IndexedColors.fromInt(c);
   } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {}

   cell = row.createCell(1);
   if (indexedcolor != null) {
    cell.setCellValue("IndexedColor." + indexedcolor.toString());
   } else {
    cell.setCellValue("No IndexedColor");
   }

   cell.setCellStyle(style);

   if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    if (indexedcolor == null) {

     HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook)workbook).getCustomPalette();

     byte[] rgb = new byte[3];
     new java.util.Random().nextBytes(rgb);
     palette.setColorAtIndex((short)c, rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);

     cell = row.createCell(2);
     cell.setCellValue("New font color index " + c 
      + " RGB=" + String.format("%02X", rgb[0]) + String.format("%02X", rgb[1]) + String.format("%02X", rgb[2]));

     cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
   }

  }

  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelFontColor.xls"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelFontColor.xlsx"));
  }
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```